# Was my question on a quote by R. G. Collingwood deleted?

Tags: discussion

I can't see it under 'Deleted Questions'.

Comment: Upvoting, as this is the first "Why was my question deleted" meta question in which I learned something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46020/what-did-r-g-collingwood-intend-to-say-by-nothing-capable-of-being-learnt-by-h) was removed by the SE "[Roomba](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)" clean-up process (RemoveDeadQuestions) on 9 June.

Comment: A History Q&A site that doesn’t preserve Q’s&A’s for historical purposes?  Something wrong there! =:-o

Comment: @KerryL Since the clean-up process is applied across all SE sites, you might want to raise that question on [Meta:SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, might do that (if I have privileges there?)

Comment: @KerryL Just sign up - like any other SE site.